# Reading from a URLConnection(php file)

Tags: java, php, urlconnection

i want to get data from a php file that is on host . its address on internet is : http://ali-nb.vcn.ir/test1.php (it has a simple data for return). i try to connect this php file and get its data but i encounter below error :

```
<b>
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script> 
<script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d) {e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("c703233d825667e15645b62e0873a2fc");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://ali-nb.vcn.ir/test1.php?i=1";</script> 
<noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
</b>
```

here is my java code :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {

            URL mylink=new URL("http://ali-nb.vcn.ir/test1.php");
            try {
                URLConnection connect=mylink.openConnection();
                connect.setDoInput(true);
                connect.setUseCaches(false);

                DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

                while((line=dis.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                System.out.println(sb.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

what's the solution ??

Comment: do `connect.connect() ` before `getInputStream` of _connection_

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani that's not necessary.

Comment: @Kayaman connection.connect() is unused?

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani the connecting happens automatically if needed, for example when calling `getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

That web page uses Javascript for its functionality. Normally your web browser will execute the Javascript and provide you with the answer, but since you're connecting directly, there's nothing that's executing the Javascript.

You could theoretically try to execute the script inside Java, but that is complex, depends on the script(s) you're trying to execute, and is a very poor solution.

So in short, what you're trying to do is something that you really shouldn't be trying to do.

Comment: tanks for replay . How should I do this?

Comment: @ali-nb some way without Javascript being involved. Maybe create an API that performs the calculation on the server side, and connect to that. The Javascript being used makes this impossible otherwise.